# Match object by array keys - Lodash

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, lodash, javascript-objects

Hello i have an array of objects that looks like:

```
[
    {
        "id": "ae588a6b-4540-5714-bfe2-a5c2a65f547b",
        "name": "Peter casa",
        "skills": [
            "javascript",
            "es6",
            "nodejs"
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": "ae588a6b-4540-5714-bfe2-a5c2a65f547a",
        "name": "Peter Coder",
        "skills": [
            "javascript",
            "es6",
            "nodejs",
            "express"
        ]
    }
]
```

and i'm trying to get the best match based on skills, i'm using lodash and the idea is resolve:

passing "skills": [
"javascript",
"es6",
"nodejs",
"express"
] get "Peter Coder" instead of  "Peter casa" because the first one match all the skills in the array given, is there any lodash method to perform this?

Edit:

In this particular example, the function needs to get the candidate with is a better fit, for instance, if i pass skills: "skills": [
"javascript",
"es6",
"nodejs"
] even if it is a perfect match for the first one i need to choose the second because it matches the skills and has more skills, so is a better match

Comment: Any reason why not to just use `array.find(value => skills.every(skill => value.skills.includes(skill)))` ?

Comment: I just Edit the question because it was incomplete, your solutions works in the first scenario but not in the second one.

Comment: Use a single es6/lodash reduce over the users, and for each iteration u return the accumulated user if his skills are a better fit  than the current one in the iteration, otherwise the current one. At the end you have directly the user with more matches out from the  reduce fn

Answer (score 1, accepted):

lodash has a method call `intersection` https://lodash.com/docs/#intersection

you can pass the array of skill and intersect it with each developer's skill. => get the length of that intersection as score and return the one with highest score.

Answer (score 2):

With lodash you could use `intersection` as @Tuan Anh Tran suggested:

```js
const users = [
  {
    id: 'ae588a6b-4540-5714-bfe2-a5c2a65f547b',
    name: 'Peter casa',
    skills: ['javascript', 'es6', 'nodejs'],
  },
  {
    id: 'ae588a6b-4540-5714-bfe2-a5c2a65f547a',
    name: 'Peter Coder',
    skills: ['javascript', 'es6', 'nodejs', 'express'],
  },
]
```

```
let skillsByUsers = {}
const skills = ['javascript', 'es6', 'nodejs', 'express']

users.map(user => {
    const skillValue = _.intersection(user.skills, skills).length
    skillsByUsersTwo = {
        ...skillsByUsersTwo,
        [user.id]: skillValue
    }
})
```

Without lodash:

```
let skillsByUsers = {}
const skills = ['javascript', 'es6', 'nodejs', 'express']

skills.map(skill => {
  users.map(user => {
    if (user.skills.includes(skill)) {
      const userSkillValue = skillsByUsers[user.id] || 0
      skillsByUsers = {
        ...skillsByUsers,
        [user.id]: userSkillValue + 1,
      }
    }
  })
})
```

they print exactly the same output:

```
lodash
{
  'ae588a6b-4540-5714-bfe2-a5c2a65f547b': 3,
  'ae588a6b-4540-5714-bfe2-a5c2a65f547a': 4
}
```

```
without lodash
{
  'ae588a6b-4540-5714-bfe2-a5c2a65f547b': 3,
  'ae588a6b-4540-5714-bfe2-a5c2a65f547a': 4
}
```